# angle brackets being interpreted as template types in a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

```
modes_[pos].variance = (sigmanew < 4) ? (4) : sigmanew > 5 * variance_ : sigmanew;
```

I have a line in a templated function of a templated class. The angle brackets in this line are being interpreted as datatype definitions and error is being thrown. How do I resolve such an issue ?

Error is :

> /(foldername)/(part_filename)_templated_impl.tpp:312:89: error: found
>   ':' in nested-name-specifier, expected '::'
>
> /(foldername)/(part_filename)_templated_impl.tpp:312:79: error:
>   'variance_' is not a class or namespace

Comment: Did you mean to type `?` instead of `*`? As in: `sigmanew > 5 ? variance_ : sigmanew`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Looks like it. Nested ternary operators are hideous. Nested ternary operators with no brackets to make it clear are even worse.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - that looks like a good explanation for the OP's problem.  I've added it as a suggestion in my answer - thanks for the good insight!

Comment: No its a multiplication. I will try adding more brackets. Everyone seems to think there is nothing wrong with angle bracket. So i'll give it one more shot writing it with more brackets to make is clearer to the compiler

Comment: @navderm: The expression has two `:` but a single `?`, that won't parse. But rather than adding braces, you should consider avoiding the ternary operator for non-trivial code.

Comment: Yeah. I made a mistake. I spent about an hour trying to resolve something that wasn't even a prob. Sorry Guys. I put them in different lines and it was much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any problems with the `<` or the `>`.  Your ternary operator has two colons in it.  That's probably not right. What it looks like you're trying is:

```
modes_[pos].variance = (sigmanew < 4) ? (4) 
                                      : (sigmanew > 5) ? variance_ 
                                                       : sigmanew;
```

But you mistyped one of the `?`s.  Why not do this operation on multiple lines instead of trying to cram it all together this way?

Comment: Yep, I did as you told and it works now! Thanks. Turned out to be a lot smaller prob. I kinda got scared that it was a templating issue